# Wowza SSL error PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Tags: ssl, java, rtmp

I have installed the SSL certificate by following https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?128-How-to-request-an-SSL-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority

The certificate was imported properly & now when i try accessing my https://HOST:8443, it's showing an SSL Error PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

JDK version is openJDK-1.6. Any suggestions to fix this issue?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it, I had to remove the braces around [password] from VHost.xml.

Comment: Remember that you can mark your own answer as accepted if it has completely solved the problem for you.

Comment: I tried that but it's telling me to wait for 2 days to mark it as answered

Comment: Oh, yeah, that strange rule.... Your answer showed up in the review queue, and the only thing I saw any reason to comment on was that it should be accepted. In that case, you should come back in two days and accept an answer whether it be your own or any other answer posted later.